Multiple Dynamic Modules - Manifest Merger Issues
Problem Statement-
I have two dynamic modules, 
one for barcode scanning - com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:18.3.0
and 
one for face detection - com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection:17.1.0
Both using google ml kit dependencies. In this, we were getting this issue (all package the same library [com.google.mlkit:vision-common].

Solution
Added common dependencies in separate project aar file, used aar as dependency. Now I am getting manifest merger issue.
 Issue: Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES@value value=(android:value) from AndroidManifest.xml:24:13-42
is also present at [:facedetector] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-33 value=(face).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-27:15 to override.
Code Github Repo
 Aar file code Github Repo
Please help here -
+------------------+    +-------------------+
|  App Module      |    |  mlkitcommon.aar  |
+---------+--------+    +---------+---------+
          |                        |
          +-----------+------------+
                      |
                      |
                      v
         +------------+-------------+
         |                          |
         v                          v
+--------+---------+     +----------+--------+
| Dynamic Module 1 |     | Dynamic Module 2  |
| - Depends on App |     | - Depends on App  |
|   Module and     |     |   Module and      |
|   mlkitcommon.aar|     |   mlkitcommon.aar |
+------------------+     +-------------------+

Related google issue tracker link
